# Changing an attribute value in a RequiredFieldValidator

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to change the value of the Enabled attribute from false to true with javascript in an asp:RequiredFieldValidator

and there is it:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator  ID="rfvPropertyName"
                        Text="*" 
                        CssClass="RedText"
                        runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="please enter your name."
                        ValidationGroup="QuerySystem"
                        ControlToValidate="txtPropertyName" Enabled="False"
                        ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: "I want to change the value of the Enabled attribute from false to true" with the help of ? button ? or what ?

Comment: client side radio button or server side ?. Can you show that line of code ?

Comment: <asp:RadioButton ID="radPropertyName" GroupName="Methods" runat="server" Text="Real Name" checked="true" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you an overview to proceed your scenario. Let me know if you have any issues with this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
        function validate() {
            var vmode = document.getElementById("rfvPropertyName");
            vmode.Visibility = visible;
        }
    </script>


<asp:RequiredFieldValidator  ID="rfvPropertyName"
                    Text="*" 
                    CssClass="RedText"
                    runat="server"
                    ErrorMessage="please enter your name."
                    ValidationGroup="QuerySystem"
                    ControlToValidate="txtPropertyName" Enabled="False"
                    ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:RadioButton ID="radPropertyName" GroupName="Methods" runat="server" Text="Real Name" checked="true" OnClientClick = "validate()" />
```

Comment: Thank you it was helpfully :) :) :)